# How to disable restrict mode in youtube?

Tags: youtube

I have problem, in not about coding, but i can't watch a lot of tutorial... I have an youtube account, in my phone anything work, but in my mac not. 
I tried to change browser , i tried also to change network, wi-fi , lan, and also broadcasting with my phone  but always the same result 
[image]

I checked in setting and if i check from the icon i have that

[image]

but if i check from youtube menu

[image]

i have this:

[image]

So i read the documentation but i don't find the solution....

How is possible disable the restricted mode ???

if i try to disable from the setting menu( second 4 pic) i have this

[image]

But i'm the admin of my pc.... there is only one account ...

help!

Comment: Just a few ideas: it is possible that *(if you don't want disable your YouTube settings)*, create a new YouTube account *(and in this new account)*, disable the restrict mode instead?. Since it will be a new account, no history will be used for show related videos. Or check this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security-winsec/unable-to-turn-off-restricted-mode-is-enabled-by/c9726802-51dd-4083-9a82-fbc40bc09ce6) but I think it is too far to follow. is there a chance that you use another PC or keep using your phone?

Comment: I did... also with out account, just as a guest.... i think is not youtube but my pc ... because in the same wifi with my phone, with another pc , with the same account i can show the video, but in my mac no!